# Script no funciona fuera de IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

El siguiente codigo lo puedo ejecutar desde IDLE(un IDE de Python ) en Python 3.6 de 32 bits sobre Windows 7(64 bits)

```
import tkinter  
def algo():
    pass
def ventanan1():
   Ventana1=tkinter.Toplevel()
   Ventana1.geometry("250x100")
   Ventana1.title("Ventana 1")
   BotonQueEjecuta1 = tkinter.Button(Ventana1, text="Ejecutar", command=ventanan2)
   BotonQueEjecuta1.place(x=0,y=0)
def ventanan2():
    Ventana2=tkinter.Toplevel()
    Ventana2.geometry("250x100")
    Ventana2.title("Ventana 2")
    BotonQueEjecuta2 = tkinter.Button(Ventana2, text="Ejecutar", command=ventanan3)
    BotonQueEjecuta2.place(x=0,y=0) 
def ventanan3():
    Ventana3=tkinter.Toplevel()
    Ventana3.geometry("250x100")
    Ventana3.title("Ventana 3")
    BotonQueEjecuta3 = tkinter.Button(Ventana3, text="Ejecutar", command=algo)
    BotonQueEjecuta3.place(x=0,y=0)
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Ventana 0") 
root.geometry("800x800")
BotonQueEjecuta = tkinter.Button(root, text="Ejecutar", command=ventanan1)
BotonQueEjecuta.place(x=0,y=0)
root.mainloop
```

El problema es al usarlo desde el interprete al estilo de "python miscript.py" sencillamente no hace nada , no tira ningún error ni nada , no muestra nada

¿Como puedo hacer para ejecutarlo desde fuera de IDLE ? solo ahí funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error en realidad es bastante simple, no estas llamando al `mainloop`, te faltan los paréntesis. Esto hace que la aplicación `tkinter` no inicie la ventana principal como no puede ser de otra manera. Simplemente la última linea es:

```
root.mainloop
```

Cuando debe ser:

```
root.mainloop()
```

La pregunta que todos nos hacemos es ¿porqué el IDLE le importa un comino que se llame o no al buble principal? Pues resulta que el mismo IDLE es una aplicación `tkinter` y tiene su propio `mainloop` interno como es lógico, esto hace que los eventos de tu programa se procesen gracias al bucle del propio IDLE.

Cuando lo lanzas usando el intérprete no hay ningún ciclo infinito esperando a los eventos de tu programa ya que no llegas a llamar al método `mainloop()` por no usar los paréntesis.

Comment: Muchas gracias , con eso mi script ya funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

Intentemos varias razones:

- No está funcionando el binding de Python en tu consola: ¿Ya probaste python, con algún otro script, desde la consola?
- La versión de python que estás corriendo es diferente a la que te corre en IDLE: ¿Puedes intentar llamar a tu python como `python3 miscript.py` y ver si eso funciona?
- Falta debuggear tu código o tu ambiente no está preparado. usa `pip install tkinter`antes de correr el codigo (Aunque dudo que este sea el problema)
- Una forma de saber si las cosas están funcionando es integrar algunos prints. Eso ayuda a separar la lógica de los problemas de SO. ¿Puedes intentar agregar unos prints para saber como está funcionando?
- La librería `tkinter` requiere `tk` que es una dependencia externa. ¿Está bien instalado? En la guía de `tk` recomiendan `ActiveTcl`. Fuente: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#installwin

Comment: Puedo ejecutar scripts sin interfaz grafica de manera normal con el interprete invocandolo como python 'nombre del script' , incluso puedo usar un programa que hice con tkinter para resolver un sistema de ecuaciones lineales desde la consola , al usar pip para instalar tkinter me dice que no encuentra una versión que satisfaga a tkinter, pero debo tenerlo instalado , de lo contrario no me funcionaria el otro script , en el enlace vienen dos comandos para ejecutar desde el interprete de python , ejecutandolos me dice que tengo la versión 8.6.6

¿ en que partes del codigo le agrego los prints?